# Percentage value when resampling GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, landsat

I am trying to resample a landsat NDSI image to a MODIS NDSI image. When I run the code below and use the inspector to click on a few random points in the image, it provides the normalized difference value at the new resolution, but then in parenthesis it provides a percentage. This not at all the points, but it looks like it is at most. I can't seem to find any info on this in the GEE developers guide. What does the percentage value correspond to? And how should I interpret it?

```
// Get information about the MODIS projection.
var Vis = {
  palette: ['000088', '0000FF', '8888FF', 'FFFFFF'],
};


var modis = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD10A1')
    .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-10-28')) 
    .first())
    .select('NDSI_Snow_Cover');


var modisProjection = modis.projection();
print('MODIS projection:', modisProjection);

// Load and display forest cover data at 30 meters resolution.
var l8NDSI = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_RT_TOA/LC08_200016_20181028')

// Load another image to replace the cloudy pixels.
var cloudMask = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(l8NDSI).select('cloud').lte(20)
var l8NDSInoClouds = l8NDSI.updateMask(cloudMask)
var l8NDSIsnow = l8NDSInoClouds.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B6'])


//////
var snow = l8NDSIsnow.select('nd')

Map.centerObject(snow,10)
Map.addLayer(snow, Vis, 'snow cover 30 m');
//Map.addLayer(l8NDSInoClouds, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 0.4}, 'masked');

// Get the snow cover data at MODIS scale and projection.
var snowMean = snow
    // Force the next reprojection to aggregate instead of resampling.
    .reduceResolution({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      maxPixels: 1024
    })
    // Request the data at the scale and projection of the MODIS image.
    .reproject({
      crs: modisProjection
    });

// Display the aggregated, reprojected forest cover data.
Map.addLayer(snowMean, Vis, 'snow cover at MODIS scale');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value displayed as a percentage by the inspector is the *mask* value of the band (multiplied by 100 to make a percentage). If the mask is 1 (100%) the percentage is not displayed; if the mask is 0, the text "masked" is displayed instead.

These partial mask values arise even though you're defining your mask with a less-than test because you are taking the mean of many pixels to make your lower-resolution pixels, and the mask of the output pixel is the mean of the masks of the input pixels. You can see on the map that they are partially transparent as displayed (the higher resolution layer appears underneath).

[image]