# Percentage value when resampling in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

Following the [Percentage value when resampling GEE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370439/percentage-value-when-resampling-gee/395772#395772).

You can see that some operations will give pixels that have a value and a (%), so:
Is there a way to make avoid or solve this and get normal pixels with just the value... so the pixels with less than 100% do not look partially transparent?

Answer (score 4):

The “percentage” value is the *mask* value. [ee.Image.updateMask](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-updatemask) will replace an image's mask wherever it is not exactly zero (= fully transparent). So:

```js
var imageWithoutPartialMask = image.updateMask(1);
```

(The `1` in this code is the new mask value; mask values are not actually stored as percentages but rather in the range `0.0` (transparent) to `1.0` (opaque).)

Note that if you are planning to get aggregated data from a region (e.g. with `reduceRegion`) this will cause the partial pixels at the edge to be over-weighted. Don't do this for images you're planning to do further computation on (unless you understand why the pixels are partially masked and know it doesn't matter or is correct for the situation); but for controlling the visualization it's fine.